# How to know retry number in Kafka-Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I know SpoutConfig has `retryLimit` to set the number of times a message can be reprocessed.

Regarding `retryLimit`, this is the message I found in SpoutConfig.class:

> Exponential back-off retry settings.  These are used by
>   ExponentialBackoffMsgRetryManager for retrying messages after a bolt
>   calls OutputCollector.fail().

I would like to know if there is any way to know the exact number of that retry when the Tuple is being processed in any given Bolt in my code.

For example if I set the `retryLimit=5` and it fails (calls `OutputCollector.fail()`) the first time when it is being reprocessed the second time i would like to know this tuple has already failed 1 time.

I would appreciate your help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for this. The tuple produced from the Kafka record by the https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/RecordTranslator.java only depends on the Kafka record, not on the number of replays.

The default RecordTranslator will emit the topic, partition and offset as part of the tuple, so you may be able to use those to check if your bolts have seen the tuple before (assuming you have a state store of some kind). Why do the bolts need to know how many times the tuples have failed?

Edit:
I think one of the reasons we haven't added failure count as an option to the emitted tuple is that it wouldn't be reliable. Since the number of failures for a tuple only exists in-memory in the spout, you could get cases where tuples fail, the spout crashes, and you never see a tuple with a failure count above 0.

Even if we had a persistent state store in the spout there would still be cases where failed tuples are not marked as such, e.g. if the spout crashes first and a previously emitted tuple then fails. The rebooted spout wouldn't recognize the tuple as previously emitted, and so wouldn't mark it as failed.

It seems to me like what you actually need to track is whether the spout has emitted a tuple more than once, rather than whether the spout thinks it has previously failed.

You might be able to use https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaTupleListener.java and `onEmit` to keep track of which offsets have been emitted more than once. Since it's running as part of the spout it should be pretty simple to clean up state as tuples are acked. There's still potential for missing a failed tuple, because `onEmit` is run after the spout emits the tuple, so if the spout crashes immediately after emitting you might miss a failure. Maybe think about whether you could design around this requirement in some way first.

Comment: Stig, thanks for your reply. In my case the bolts need to know the number because business wants to give special treatment (insert in an error table to reprocess them EoD) to those tuples that have failed.

Comment: Edited answer since the comment got too big

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stig, I will give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge Storm doesn't provide built-in support for this.

I have tried with below-mentioned implementation:

```
    public class AuditMessageWriter extends BaseBolt {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        Map<Object, Integer> failedTuple = new HashMap<>();

        public AuditMessageWriter() {

        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
            this.collector = collector;
            //any initialization if u want
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void execute(Tuple input) {
            try {

            //Write your processing logic
            collector.ack(input);
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            //In case of any exception save the tuple in failedTuple map with a count 1
            //Before adding the tuple in failedTuple map check the count and increase it and fail the tuple

            //if failure count reaches the limit (message reprocess limit) log that and remove from map and acknowledge the tuple
            log(input);
            ExceptionHandler.LogError(e2, "Message IO Exception");
            }

        }

        void log(Tuple input) {

            try {
                //Here u can pass result to dead queue or log that
//And ack the tuple 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ExceptionHandler.LogError(e, "Exception while logging");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cleanup() {
            // To declare output fields.Not required in this alert.
        }

        @Override
        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
            // To declare output fields.Not required in this alert.
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
            return null;
        }

    }
```